# Cannot find HTML resource for file in RESTful project

Tags: eclipse, rest, tomcat6

I have been trying to implement a RESTful web service by following the tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html).

I have been searching online for the issue I am encountering but without any help. When implementing the CRUD web service, the article includes an HTML file. I have tried putting it both in WebContent and in WebContent/WEB-INF, but I cannot get it to work. I have also tried applying the solutions listed [here](http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/restful.html), but the HTML file still didn't work.

The other functions do work, it's just this that I am having a problem with. I tried using:

```
localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.todo/rest/create_todo.html
localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.todo/create_todo.html
localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.todo/WEB-INF/create_todo.html
```

The error I am getting is from Tomcat not finding the resource.

Nothing works and I would really appreciate any help I can get. :)